# CodeIgniter input class outside codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, input, integration

I'm moving an app from flat file php to codeigniter and I'd like to integrate the two as much as possible before moving over completely.  I'm looking to specifically use the input class outside of codeigniter but it looks like I'd also need to use the controller logic (to get access to input segments).  Can anyone walk me through using the input library in a flat file php?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "I'd like to integrate the two as much as possible before moving over completely", but what exactly are you trying to accomplish by using the Input class outside of CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're creating too much work and potential problems by trying to do this. You'll be better off if you go directly to CI. Move any standalone functions in your standard PHP files into Helper functions.

If you really want to do this, you could use CI and create controllers/functions for all your files, then in the controller functions, just `include()` your PHP file and ignore the models and view for now. That way you'll have access to all the CI variables, including the `$this->input` data.

Comment: Thanks unfortunately moving completely is not an option right now.  I'll post if I get something worked out.